# Setting Framework Search Paths?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have an XCode project where when I click on Project->Edit Project Settings I have things set to iOS 3.2, but when I build, XCode sets the Framework Search Paths to iPhoneOS3.0.sdk.  I've set the following using Project->Edit Project Settings:

1. Base SDK = iPhone Device 3.2
2. iPhone OS Deployment Target = iPhone Device 3.2
3. Targeted Device Family = iPad

Does anyone know what setting XCode is using to set the Framework Search Paths to iPhoneOS3.0.sdk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I found was to go to the Target Info and delete the Framework search path that XCode created.  Then everything compiled correctly.